# Upgrade php version of xampp not success

Tags: php

Today I decided to upgrade my xampp to new php version (5.6.11). I have downloaded and configured everything based on what Google said. After resetting the server, it runs successfully. But when I check xampp's phpinfo, it has not been updated.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJfNv.png)

What have I missed?

Comment: what did you meant by not update ? it has 5.6.11\php.ini

Comment: Yea it shows 5.6.11 in the php info lol ?

Answer (score 0):

1. back up your `htdocs` files and database.
2. Download [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).
3. Uninstall XAMPP from your control panel.
4. Manually remove `xampp` folder from your partition.
5. Install it back

Problem solved